# Unicode error when reading a csv file with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, encoding

Why pandas is not able to read this csv file and returns 'UnicodeEncodeError'. I tried lot of solutions from stackoverflow (local download, different encoding, change the engine...), but still not working...How to fix it?

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'http://é.com'

pd.read_csv(url,encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Thanks, but encoding="latin1" is not working

Comment: It is not about encoding, it is about format. This is not a CSV but an GZ archive not the same thing.

Comment: in the gz, it is a csv...Pandas read csv handles this type of format (because it is working with other files)

Comment: The problem comes from the `é` in your URL, see my updated answer.

Comment: thanks for the solution! accent in url...

Comment: Your edit on my answer is wrong. I never stated é can be replaced be e, you have to escape é as I did in my initial statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

Your URL contains non ASCII character as the error complains.

Just change:

```
url = 'http://é.com'
```

For:

```
url = 'http://%C3%A9.com'
```

And the problem is fixed.

### Solutions

#### Automatic URL escaping

Reading the error in depth shows that after executing the request to get resource behind the URL, the `read_csv` function expects the URL of resource to be ASCII encoded which seems not the be the case for this specific resource.

This call that is made by `read_csv` fails miserably:

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlopen(url)
```

The problem is due to the accent in `é` that must be escaped to prevent `urlopen` to fail. Below a clean way to enforce this requirement:

```
import urllib.parse

result = urllib.parse.urlparse(url)
replaced = result._replace(path=urllib.parse.quote(result.path))
url = urllib.parse.urlunparse(replaced)

pd.read_csv(url)
```

#### Handling dataflow by yourself

Alternatively you can by pass this limitation by handling the complete flow by yourself. Following snippet does the trick:

```
import io
import gzip
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = 'http://é.com'
response = requests.get(url)
file = io.BytesIO(response.content)
with gzip.open(file, 'rb') as handler:
     df = pd.read_csv(handler)
```

The key is to get the HTTP resource and deflate it then fake the content as a file-like object because `read_csv` does read directly CSV strings.